# Push notification using Google Cloud Messaging error

Tags: android, push-notification

I am a beginner in Android.  I'm trying to learn Push notification using Google Coud Messaging
this is the print screen for this error

Gradle DSL method not found
Possible causes:

The project 'Save' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
Open Gradle wrapper file

The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
Apply Gradle plugin

in photo 5

can anyone help me

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your android studio to latest version to latest version.